# How to disable checkbox based on user selection in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to disable checkboxes depending on list of variables. For example if user selects "Spain" in a Listbox only some checkbox currencies should be allowed.

1. I have a table of currencies with value one or zero based on the user selection and this get update. Zero means currency is not available.
2. I have a macro which reads the list and will disable or enable the individual list boxes. However this as a Worksheet_Change even" and it doesn't get called via the Listbox selection change. Although my range gets updated after user makes the selection.
   So I think I need a Module based macro which would be called when user makes a Listbox selection, but struggle to modify my current macro.

My current code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim R As Range, c As Range, cb As OLEObject

' set a range where the cell will be either 1 or 0 depending on country selection

Set R = Me.Range("C115:C135")
If Not Intersect(Target, R) Is Nothing Then

' sets the checbox to zero if related cell value in range is zero

    For Each c In Intersect(Target, R)
        For Each cb In Me.OLEObjects
        ' Identifies the relevant Checkbox name based on related cell address
            If cb.Name Like "CheckBox" & Val(Split(c.Address, "$")(2)) - 14 Then
                cb.Enabled = c.Value > 0
            End If
        Next cb
    Next c
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try calling the `Worksheet_Change` event from the own Listbox `change` event with `Call Worksheet_Change`

Comment: Thank you for the advice @PEH. I did inserted the code below, but nothing seems to happen?       Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
                                    Worksheet_Change Range("A1")
                                    End Sub

Comment: If you assign a cell to hold the value of the listbox selection then that cell's change will fire the worksheet change event.

Comment: Hi @Harassed, the cell changes when selection is made at the listbox, but it doesnt trigger the change event. Only if I make the change manually directly in the cell. Then the macro works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be kind of tricky here.

First of all, **in the desired worksheet where you have the code you have posted**, write a new sub like this:

```
Sub MyMacro()
Call Worksheet_Change(ActiveCell) 'change ActiveCell for the range you want to be the target
End Sub
```

Then, from the event `Change` of the Listbox, try:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Call Hoja1.MyMacro 'Replace Hoja1 with the name of your worksheet in VBA.
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Foxfire And Burns And Burns, Thank you for the help. I have added you macro above. But I am not sure what to use in replacement of the (ActiveCell) in first macro? Currently both of the macro runs (I added a message box after the Call in MyMacro), but nothing happens then?!

Comment: I have played with the macro further and there seems to be some problem in the main macro. I can actually trigger it from the Listbox and it runs as it displays the two Msg boxes, but it does not change the Checkboxes. If I however change the range in the spreadsheet directly the change_even runs and updates the Checkboxes correctly:

Comment: Macro:Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim R As Range, c As Range, cb As OLEObject

MsgBox "hello", vbOKOnly


Set R = Me.Range("C115:C135")
If Not Intersect(Target, R) Is Nothing Then

    For Each c In Intersect(Target, R)
        For Each cb In Me.OLEObjects
            If cb.Name Like "CheckBox" & Val(Split(c.Address, "$")(2)) - 14 Then
                cb.Enabled = c.Value > 0
            End If
        Next cb
    Next c
    End If
    
MsgBox "hello number 2", vbOKOnly
    
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to modify the macro so it can be used directly in the modul and called directly from the list box. See below. Thank you all for your advise.
Sorry I struggle to indent the full code.

```
Public Sub Checkboxupdate()

Dim R As Range, c As Range, cb As OLEObject, hb As CheckBox

Set R = Range("C115:C135")
If Not R Is Nothing Then

    For Each c In R
    On Error Resume Next
        For Each cb In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
            If cb.Name Like "CheckBox" & Val(Split(c.Address, "$")(2)) - 14 Then

                cb.Enabled = c.Value > 0

            End If
        Next cb
    Next c
    End If

    MsgBox "Currency availability updated.", vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like you're using a `Form` or `ActiveX` listbox.  You could use the _Data Validation_ list which would fire on a `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: Hi @Darren Bartrup-Cook, the problem with data validation I had was that it didn't show the scroll button. Although I guess there is a way to change the display.